# What does "statically assign" mean for gl_FragDepth?

Tags: glsl

The documentation for `gl_FragDepth`, contains the phrase "If a shader statically assigns to gl_FragDepth... ." What does "statically" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### GLSL ES 1.00 specification

**7.2 Fragment Shader Special Variables**

> (A shader contains a static assignment to a variable x if, after pre-processing, the shader contains a
> statement that would write to x, whether or not run-time flow of control will cause that statement to be
> executed.)